# Model Binding a List MVC3 not reading vaules

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, binding, model, action

I have read some posts, but I still find it difficult to solve this. My problem is that my action only reads some of the values from the binded list. This is how I send the list to the view:

```
public ActionResult RegisterSurvey()
    {
        RegisterSurveyModel model = new RegisterSurveyModel();

        var questions = new List<QuestionModel>();
        var survey = EFSurvey.Survey.FirstOrDefault();
        survey.QuestionSurvey
            .Where(x => x.AuditingDeleted == false)
            .Where(x => x.Active == true).ToList().ForEach((item) =>
            {
                var questionModel = new QuestionModel();
                ModelCopier.CopyModel(item, questionModel);
                questionModel.Answer = string.Empty;

                questions.Add(questionModel);

            });
        model.Questions = questions;
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is my model:

```
public class RegisterSurveyModel
{
    public List<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; } 
}

public class QuestionModel
{
    public int QuestionSurveyID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public bool Suggestion { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="SiteSurveyContainer">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="SurveyUp">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (!Model.Questions[i].Suggestion)
            {
            <p>@Model.Questions[i].Question</p>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Questions[i].QuestionSurveyID);
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Questions[i].Answer, new { @class = "surveyBox" });
            }
        }
    </div>
    <div class="SurveyBottom">
        <div class="line">
        </div>
        <p>
            Suggestions</p>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Where(x => x.Suggestion == true).Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Questions[i].QuestionSurveyID);
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.Questions[i].Answer, new { @class = "surveyTextArea" })
        }
    </div>
    <div class="surveyBottomButton">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Results" />
    </div>
}
```

So far so good. Anyway, when I answer all of the survey questions, I only get the first 4 answers... Weird. Anyone knows why is that happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple input controls with within the same form with the same name.

Suggested questions are a sub set of all questions, so they are being repeated twice on the same form. That will throw off the ModelBinder, so your receiving action is probably only seeing the questions that have not been repeated.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that a minute ago while looking at the generated markup. But also, I dont know why, the if statement in the first set was somehow braking the binding, so what I did was to separate normal questions in one list and suggested question in another list instead of having them all in one and filtering. That made the binding work normally.